# Customizing UIModalViewController Size and Having a Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've created my own `ProfileUIViewController` class that is a `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.  I display this view in two ways:

1. From an IBAction within `A-UIViewController.m`, as a `UIModalViewController`.  `A-UIViewController` has a `UINavigationBar` when it's loaded, but when I display the modal, it no longer has the navigation bar.
2. From clicking a table cell row within `B-UIViewController.m`, by pushing it onto the stack.  `B-UIViewController` has a `UINavigationBar` when it's loaded, and the `ProfileViewController` keeps the navBar as desired :)

What I am looking to do is keep the UINavigationBar when the view is loaded as a modal in case 1, filling in INSIDE the UINavigationBar instead of laying over the entire view.  (IE, I would like the modal to appear within `A-UIViewConroller` underneath the navBar - making it a smaller size)

Can someone help me with this?  Do I need to make my own custom `ModalViewController` class - wouldn't this be `ProfileUIViewController`?  Does it need some instance methods that I'm not giving it?  Any direction would be great:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation bar is managed by the navigation controller, not by your view controller. When you push your view controller into the navigation controller, the navigation controller uses the information in the navigationItem to determine what to put in the navigation bar. But when you display your view controller modally, it's not inside any navigation controller so there is no bar.

One simple solution for the modal case is to create a new UINavigationController with your view controller as its root view controller, and display that modally instead of displaying your view controller directly.

Comment: Would I want to create that new `UINavigationController` INSIDE `A-UIViewController` for my case?  Make the root viewController of the new navigationController to `A-UIViewController`, and then display that `UINavController` modally? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You probably have something like `[self presentModalViewController:profileController animated:YES]`. Change it to `UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:profile] autorelease]; [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];`

Comment: Anomie - Thanks!  This at least got me with a working navBar across the top.  The reason I was confused is I was already calling `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:profileVC animated:YES]`. What I would REALLY like is the modal to be displayed UNDERNEATH my current NavBar that is displayed inside `A-UIViewController` instead of creating a totally new navBar.

Comment: Why not just push it on the stack? The point of displaying a view controller modally is to temporarily replace the current interface with a new one, not to keep part of the old interface around.

Comment: True. I thought about that, but I don't want the view to push onto the stack the normal way.  If I push, it just slides right to the new view; can I customize the norm to have it display similar to a modal?